# How can i get Id of checked round-input in php?

Tags: php

I am doing php email sender and i got difficulties. One of the form's parts is radio inputs where user need to choose one. I need to get the id of element and write it in the email (for example: "Room type: Room2").

```
<div id="roomsContainer">
        <input type="radio" name="roomType" id="Room1" data-customInfo="some information about room"/>    
        <label for="Room1" class="roomTypeLabel"><div class="roomDiv">Room1</div></label>

        <input type="radio" name="roomType" id="Room2" />    
        <label for="Room2" class="roomTypeLabel"><div class="roomDiv">Room2</div></label>
    .....
</div>
```

GPT offering me this code but it leads to result of "Room Type: on". I don't know PHP myself. How can i correct the code? So Room Type would display chosen input ID or even better, chosen element 'data-' tag?

```
 $roomType = $_POST['roomType'];
    $body .= "Room Type: $roomType\n";
```

Comment: Give both of those radio inputs a `value` attribute, to _specify_ which value you want them to submit when checked.

Comment: "GPT offering me this code" — Try learning from a tutorial or language reference instead of a next-word-prediction engine.

Comment: @Quentin if only it was as easy to just find exact tutorial. Most of chunks I get from GPT are working or understandable enough for me to rework. Here is just language I don't know at all. But I understand it is overrated as hell (at least free version)

Comment: Looking for "exact tutorials" is a problem. You need to look for [general tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms) and then apply what you learn to your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `id` attribute is to uniquely identify an element **on the client** with the main uses being to link to a specific part of a page, reference the element with the `for` attribute of a label, and target it with CSS and JavaScript. It is not designed to be sent to the server. You cannot get it with PHP.

When a form is submitted to a server the data is derived from the `name`s and `value`s of the successful controls.

Any data you want to send to the server should, therefore, be stored in the `value` attribute.

```
 <input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" checked>
```

and

```
 $result = $_POST['foo'];
```